# Rails with apache2 trailing slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I have a static html site in `public/hello` directory, In production this `hello` directory is served by my Apache2 server with `example.com/hello/`.

But when I goto `example.com/hello` this shows 404 not found. Whereas `example.com/hello/`(trailing slash) works fine.

The problem is I don't want that trailing slash at the end. How can I achieve this for rails specific app?

I've `AllowOverride All` in my `.conf` file. I've tried other methods like `DirectorySlash off` etc, but they are not working.

What exactly should be in my `.htaccess` file, also in rails app where should I place `.htaccess` file, Also what other than `AllowOverride All` I must have in `.conf` file?